# How do you confirm a website is decentralized?

Tags: decentralized-identity

If you look at DApps like Sushiswap, Pancakeswap, Curve, AAVE etc, how do you actually confirm that the web interface is hosted on Web3.0, ie a decentralized host server?

The Dapp looks indistinguishable from a regular website hosted on a single server.

Comment: What is a 'decentralized host server'? Just sounds like another name for load balancing or ddos protection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a decentralized host server

Nobody is using decentralised hosting today, because it is not practical yet. Thus, any web frontend hosting is centralised by definition. Somewhere, there is a phone number and password that holds the domain name registration entry, as mainstream web browsers do not support any decentralised DNS or decentralised HTTP replacement protocol.

It is only smart contracts that are decentralised.

Comment: so the Dapps like Uniswap or AAVE are all just regular websites? How do you check this? Because guys on twitter were saying it cannot 'go offline' since its distributed.

Comment: You do not check it, because it cannot be anything else. You do not check if the sky is still out there. But it is just a frontend. You can always directly interact with smart contracts with your own Ethereum node without frontend. But to understand this, you need to first  understand what is frontend, backend and blockchain.

Comment: thanks i kept wondering how decentralized webpages would work with the current http protocols. but the amount of unverifited 'manufactured-truth' in the crypto community is quite staggering.

Comment: You are free to checkout the source code from Github and run it locally on your computer.

Comment: yes sure i get that part. tx. just that for a 'normal' person if they wanted to place their money in these contracts the continued operation of such Dapps websites would be a very important consideration. 'normal' people wont be able to rebuild the Dapps if it went offline. of course other people might clone it and get it working again though.

Comment: Being possible and being difficult are two different things. For any customer, it is impossible to check if their credit card or bank is actually any solid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233744/discussion-between-andiana-and-mikko-ohtamaa).

Comment: You may want to have a look into the Brave browser and how it integrates with IFPS: https://brave.com/brave-integrates-ipfs/

Comment: IPFS is a cache, not hosting solution.